# Run time error 424, issues with defining variables

Tags: vba, loops, variables, runtime-error

i am having troubles after fixing next variable issues. I am now getting run time errors 424. I believe this is because i am not naming my variables correctly as strings or Integers. I have two methods to the code and they are both resulting in the same error.

Columns 11 and 1 are text that need to match
Column 10 and columns(v) are dates that need to match
Column 2 will be text with a number at the end
Columns(V) will be a number with a number at the end

the logic of the loop makes sense to me but can't figure out what's causing the issue.

**If cell.Value(J, 11) = Master.cell.Value(P, 1) And cell.Value(J, 10) = Master.cell.Value(P, V) Then**

error Produced here "Run time '424' Object Required, What object am i missing? (error in bold)

```
  Sub IndexInfo()
'
' Loops through data and finds matches and then indexs information
'
Dim J As Integer
Dim P As Integer
Dim V As Integer
Dim Master As Worksheet
Dim Gracie As Worksheet

IRowL = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set Master = Worksheets("Master")
Set Gracie = Worksheets("Gracie")


For J = 2 To IRowL
    For V = 21 To 50
        For P = 2 To IRowL
        


If Gracie.Cells(J, 11).Value = Master.Cells(P, 1).Value And Gracie.Cells.Value(J, 10) = Master.Cells(P, V).Values Then

Gracie.Cells(J, 30).Value = Master.Cells(P, 2).Value And Gracie.Cells(J, 31).Value = Master.Cells(1, V).Value

            Else
        End If
     Next P
   Next V
Next J

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line(s) are triggering the error? What's the text of the error? Please click the "edit" button below your answer to add this information AND format the code indenting so that it makes sense.

Comment: Let me know if the edits helps explain the issue any further @CindyMeister

Comment: That's an improvement, yes. I believe the problem is that Master.cell doesn't point to a specific object? It's also not clear what object `cell`is - these objects aren't declared or instantiated in the code you show us (there's no `Dim` and no `Set` for them). Do you have that somewhere else (and please show us) or have you not done that?

Comment: Your structure is off.  It should be {SheetReference}.Cells([RowIndex],[ColumnIndex].Value  (where SheetReference is whatever sheet you're working on).   Also, you have to set Master = to a sheet.  Have a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221357(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: Agree with sous, rather than use "cell.Value" use a variable for each worksheet then say myWorksheetVariable.cells(j, whatever number)

Comment: I added the suggestions above but am still getting errors. i feel like it's with my declared variables. essentially all this is doing is comparing two cells from a row in the Gracie Sheet from an array and if it's matches both to a row from (Master sheet) the array it grabs information from the matching row. Is there flaw in the logic by not using Boolean?